# How to use background css for an image not in the Content or Resource folder

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a background image for an input, just using inline styling because it would be changed with javascript later:

`<input type="text" style="background: url('??') no-repeat;" />`

What do I put as the `url`? This is the directory structure:

[image: Directory Structure]

(Where above `Views` is just the root project folder)

The input is on `MyPage`. I've tried using `/Views/1/2/3/Content/images/somePic.jpg`, but it apparently could not be found, which is confusing as it had worked before when I just had it in `Root/Resources/somePic.jpg` and linked it as `Resources/somePic.jpg`.

I don't have a choice over which directory this image is in. How do I link it properly with this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh nevermind, the problem apparently lay in something completely irrelevant. There was a line in `Web.config` that essentially said to give a 404 error for all content in the `Views` folder. The fix was to just add an exception for the `Content` folder. The path I've been using did work; it was just a permissions problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

`background: url(http://healthbenefitsohio.com/images/logo.png) no-repeat;`

By finding out the exact url to the image you can use that imageURL as a source to it. This is not the best way but if the direct folder route is not working then this is an option. Why would a direct route to the image not work is what I don't understand.

I also just noticed this, is MyPage.cshtml on the same tier as the image or after it?

If it is on the same tier then try:

`background: url(images/somePic.gif) no-repeat;`

By using:

`background: url(/Views/1/2/3/Content/images/somePic.gif) no-repeat;`

Will cause problems because the MyPage is inside the Content folder, inside that folder there is no views, 1, 2, 3, and so forth for previous files. You didn't allow the file to know hey you need to go a folder back or forward by using the `../`

Comment: I'm using route mapping with mac addresses so I essentially have no idea what the exact url would be, though it does seem to show up right on the rendered page (essentially as `http://somemac/Views/1/2/3/Content/images/somePic.gif`). MyPage.cshtml is after the image directory (under `Content`).

Comment: So is images inside content or out of it? I also added more to my answer.

Comment: `images` is inside content. The thing with using just `url(images/somePic.gif)` (which I also thought should work) is that it gets rendered out as `http://somemac/images/somePic.jpg`, bypassing the parent directories completely.

Comment: This is a long shot but try this `background: url(../Views/1/2/3/Content/images/somePic.gif);`

Comment: The last long shot I could think of is `background: url(../../../../Views/1/2/3/Content/images/somePic.gif);` I don't see why just using `/` doesn't seem to do the trick. By just using `/` it should be finding the root folder regardless but you can try this if you have not. `background: url(/images/somePic.gif);`

Comment: Interestingly it's completely ignoring all the `../` in the rendered url. `/images/` doesn't work either, but thanks for the help!

Comment: I apologize that my help wasn't very useful this time but I will try later, not at work, to find something out for you.